# running docker container dns flag with a cname instead of ip address of nameserver

Tags: docker, dns, cname

I am trying to pass dns nameserver via cname. I used below command

```
docker run -d --dns=dnsserver.testdomain.com image
```

It is throwing me an error saying

```
"--dns":flag dnsserver.testdomain.com is not an ip address.
```

I understand the error, but I have a situation where my dns server can change and I want to handle it via cname so that even if the ip address of name server changes my dns queries inside container will not fail.

Can you please help me in resolving this?
Also I need to ultimately integrate this with ECS task definition.

Answer (score 1):

That is consistent with the way [moby opts validate IP addresses](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/3a633a712c8bbb863fe7e57ec132dd87a9c4eff7/opts/opts.go#L228-L235).

If you need to use a cname, you should wrap your docker run call in a script which:

- will resolve the FQDN (fuly qualified domain name) to an IP address ([ping or other commands](https://serverfault.com/q/74042/783))
- use that IP address in your `-dns` option.

For the script, see "[AWS ECS 'Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)".

You can then use that value (IP address) in your [AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html) directive.